# Book with creatures like bugs in a box that the book told not to open

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book that I can't quite remember the title or author of. As far as I remember it is a young kids or teens book.

It's about these very smart bug-like creatures that I believe are metal or something high-tech. The human doesn't listen about not opening the box and that is what the story plot seems to be about from what I remember. Please help me. I thought it was something called 'The Box- Don't Open it'. But I can't find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78867/ya-novel-kid-finds-some-kind-of-time-traveling-creature (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

Your description is a reasonably close match to [*The Boxes*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0780799445) by William Sleator.  From Amazon.com:

> Annie's Uncle Marco goes on one of his mysterious trips, leaving her in charge of two sealed boxes on one condition: she must not open either one while he is away. But she is tempted...and soon she has unleashed the unspeakable. The creatures inside the box are crab-like and grotesque. And they possess a power Annie could never have imagined: the power to transmute time.