# YA novel - kid finds some kind of time traveling creature

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I have a very, very vague recollection of this book that I read around 1999-2001.

A kid or tweenager finds some kind of creature -- the visual image in my mind is of something like a horseshoe crab but that's hardly reliable -- that I think can time travel, or allows him to time travel. Unfortunately that's about all I remember of it, but it was such a distinctively weird concept that hopefully someone else remembers it as well.

The overall vibe seemed "dark" to me, as a young person. There might have been another kid involved later on.

Comment: Doesn't ring any bells. You don't have anything more?

Comment: @MrLister unfortunately no. I think the book might have been a gray paperback and I think it might have come through that Scholastic book catalogue kids used to get.

Comment: One kid, not a group of kids? Was the critter furry?

Comment: @Lexible I don't remember it being furry. I think it wasn't a "cute" critter

Comment: The horseshoe crab reminds me of William Sleator's 'Marco's Millions' (2001) and 'The Boxes' (1998?).

Comment: @Frock I'm amazed! It was indeed _The Boxes_ and you should post that answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just might be William Sleator's *[The Boxes](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Boxes.html?id=T5744LFVnFoC)* ;-)
Published 1998.

[image]

The creatures on the cover look crablike, and the date seems right.

Answer (score 1):

A book that came to mind was The Five Children and It by E. Nesbit. The children find a ugly creature called a psammead in a gravel pit. It doesn't look like a horseshoe crab, but is furry and has eyes on stalks. It grants the children wishes, I think one includes sending them back in time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the comments above indicate that this is the wrong answer.

Comment: A good book, though.