# Box containing hive of insectoid aliens alters boy's experience of time

Tags: story-identification, books

I have a very fond memory of a book that I read at some point in elementary school. It may have been classified as young adult or adult, I'm not sure.

All I can remember about it is that it revolves around a boy in possession of a box that contains a hive of some kind of alien or being that has the ability to alter the boy's experience of time, and that the beings were spider like or insectoid in appearance.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Sounds like it has elements of *Ender's Game* and later books in the saga that focus on the Formic aliens, also called buggers, that look like ants.  Did this book involve any spaceships or other sci-fi elements?

Comment: By the way, this is not a forum, not a discussion board. It's a Q&A site. Just the questions and answers, not the fluff.

Comment: @CreationEdge with elements of *Perdido Street Station* and *A Deepness in the Sky* thrown in... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78867/ya-novel-kid-finds-some-kind-of-time-traveling-creature

Comment: The other thing wrong with your post (after calling Stack Exchange a "forum") is that (especially since you don't disclose your age) telling us *how old you were* when you read the book doesn't help us much.  It's more useful to specify a date (or date range); also, where you were at the time.  You talk about "a book", so I assume you mean a novel; you should make that explicit.  What type of book was it (hardback or paperback)?  Do you remember anything about the cover?  Do you think it was new when you read it?  Etc.

Comment: P.S. Asking people to "get in contact" with you is superfluous.  You asked a question; if people have any ideas, they'll post answers.

Answer (score 10):

Your description is a reasonably close match to [*The Boxes*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0780799445) by William Sleator.  From Amazon.com:

> Annie's Uncle Marco goes on one of his mysterious trips, leaving her in charge of two sealed boxes on one condition: she must not open either one while he is away. But she is tempted...and soon she has unleashed the unspeakable. The creatures inside the box are crab-like and grotesque. And they possess a power Annie could never have imagined: the power to transmute time.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [Speaker for the dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_for_the_Dead) by Orson Scott Card, the sequel to Enders Game, about Andrew "Ender" Wiggin.

> Ender finds himself in posession of the last Hive Queen, the race thought obliterated in the first book.

The "hive" doesn't so much alter his perception of time, but he comes to realise

> The Hive Queen doesn't experience relativistic effects while travelling at near-light speeds, she experiences the full length of the centuries that pass, not the weeks and months that Ender experiences