# Old book about a child who found a box containing aliens that could alter gravity and time

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

When I was about 12 (c. 2002), I read a fiction book, but today I can't remember its title or who wrote it. May have been a two part series, and I'm not sure how old the book was at the time.

Protagonist was a child, found a box that could not be opened normally.  I remember they had to put their head on the lid, with their hands on the sides and rotate their hands in opposite directions.  The box lid would then disappear and inside was a species of sentient insectoid aliens.  I remember they said "Have you eaten well?" as a formal greeting.  The box also contained a smaller box with a dial on it.

The dial would alter gravity, which would affect how the holder perceived time, as well as the weight of the containment box.  Increasing the gravity made the box heavier while time sped up around the holder.  Decreasing gravity would make the box lighter while slowing time around the holder.

I don't remember much about the plot, but at one point the box containing the aliens was taken by a group of people (possibly a government agency), and the protagonist had to use the dial to get the box back.  There was also something dealing with the protagonist's uncle.  I believe he had gone missing, but later on it's found that he had a working replica of the dial, and was using it to slow time for himself, allowing him to live a great deal of time without aging.

Comment: Thats exactly it!!!! Thank you!!!!! <3

Comment: If the answer is "The Boxes", a question linked from that one has an accepted answer. Please confirm that the answer is "The Boxes".

Comment: Specifically https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78867/ya-novel-kid-finds-some-kind-of-time-traveling-creature?noredirect=1&lq=1. I saw the description and thought, "That's got to be a Sleator novel".

Comment: see OP confirmation comment above

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear which answer is being provided, this is good match for William Sleator's *[The Boxes](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/william-sleator/the-boxes/)*.

[image: Front cover of *The Boxes*]

> Sleator (*The Beasties*, 1997, etc.) offers a strained mix of aliens and time travel in this tepid work of science fiction. When Annie, 15, is entrusted with two mysterious boxes by her secretive, young-looking Uncle Marco, her reaction is entirely understandable: She opens both. The first crate releases a crab-like creature that asexually reproduces in the basement of her Aunt Ruth’s house; the second, in her bedroom, reveals a clock-like device that can slow the flow of time. Of course, the boxes are somehow connected—the clock, which the crab-creatures refer to as “Lord,” enables them to erect a miniature palace within a very short time. Rather than focus on the aliens, the story shifts to the evil Crutchley Development Corporation, which, while buying up local houses to erect a super mall, discovers the secret in Annie’s basement, and steals the clock device. With her friend, Henry, Annie escapes the clutches of Crutchley employees and relatives, and returns with the clock, which, Uncle Marco divulges, is the key to his youthful appearance. As the Crutchley team bursts in, the crab creatures create a vortex through which the three humans escape. That lets Sleator off the hook for the moment, without providing any real explanation, and negates all chances for a satisfying ending. Readers will have to wait to see if there’s a sequel.

No sequel was written, and [Sleator died in 2001](https://www.npr.org/2011/08/11/139551835/remembering-william-sleators-haunting-tales), but it does have a prequel, *[Marcos's Millions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco%27s_Millions)*.